# R scan two columns and keep unique

Tags: r, large-files

I have a tab-separated data file with four columns out of which I would like to read the first two in R, and only keep the unique 2-column pairs as a `data.frame`. The file can be in the millions of rows:

```
cluster-1    3    12412341324    13412341234
cluster-1    3    62626662346    54234524354
cluster-1    3    45454345354    45454544545
cluster-2    644  12332234341    37535473475
cluster-2    644  54654365466    56565634543
cluster-2    644  56356356536    35634563456
...
cluster-9999999    123    123412341241    143132423
...
```

I would like to use `scan` (or any better option) to read the file and end up with a `data.frame` that has:

```
cluster-1    3
cluster-2    644
cluster-3    343
...
cluster-9999999    123
```

What would be the most time-efficient way of reading this large files in R?

Comment: do you know how many columns are there in your file?

Comment: @Arun: not before I run it, I only know it's between 10E6 and 10E8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Known and relatively few columns**: If you know the number of columns, say, 5 columns and you want the first two columns (or there are only few columns) then, this can be done using `colClasses` from `read.table`:

```
# header here is set to false because I don't see one in your file
df <- read.table("~/file.txt", header = FALSE, 
              colClasses=c("character", "numeric", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"))
```

Here, we set the 3rd to 5th column to `NULL` so that they are skipped.

**Unknown columns/Lot of columns:** Another alternative if you don't know the columns or there are too many is to use `pipe` with `awk` (or `pipe` with `cut` for that matter) to filter the file first with the columns you require and then load it using `read.table`:

```
# header here is set to false because I don't see one in your file
df <- read.table(pipe("awk '{print $1\"\t\"$2}' ~/file.txt"), 
                       header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

**Remove duplicated rows**: Use `duplicated` from `base` as:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

Comment: if number of columns are unknown, one can read only 1 line from the data file and deduce number of and col classes of column from that

Comment: @Arun: thanks, pipe worked wonderfully, even adding "| uniq" to it speed it up massively: `"awk '{print $1\"\t\"$2}' ~/file.txt | uniq"`